# The Outlook add-in displayDialogAsync has unintended behavior

Tags: outlook, office365, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm creating an add-in on Outlook on the Web, and I'm seeing unexpected behavior when I test it.

In the Web version of Outlook, when I compose a message on the compose screen and click the "Send" button
A dialog box should appear, but it does not. Also, I am unable to send the email.

1)The event occurs even when the sample code described in the official reference is executed.

```
var dialog; Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://localhost:3000/index.html', 
{height: 30, width: 20, displayInIframe: true},

function (asyncResult) { dialog = asyncResult.value; dialog.addEventHandler(
Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage); } 
);[enter image description here][1]
```

2)The same behavior occurs when the sample code in (1) is incorporated into the official sample project files available on github.

■sample code link
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send

3)When the event occurs, don't go to connect to the URL that is given as an argument in displayDialogAsync.

4)The problem definitely occurs when I access Outlook on the web and immediately click "New Message" to go to the compose screen.

5)No error message is displayed when a problem occurs.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code? Do you get any errors in the code?

Comment: Please answer the below questions to help us understand further. 
1. Was it working before and did it break recently for you?
2. Can you reproduce the issue every time or is it not persistent. 
3. Do you see any errors when it doesn't work?
4. Can you share a sample manifest where the same is reproable?

Comment: Dear Eugene. 
Thank you very much for your message. I respond to your questions with the following.
Yes, I tried  debugging. but Don't see Related error logs.

Comment: Dear Outlook Add-ins Team,
Thank you very much for your message. I respond to your questions with the following.

Comment: 1. It's broken from before. 2. it's not persistent. After composing a "New Message" and pressing the Send button, the dialog freezes without opening. 3. I Don't see errors. also I tried debugging with tools but Don't see Related error logs. 4. Share the URL where sample manifest-file. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-On-Send/blob/master/outlook-add-in-on-send/Contoso%20Message%20Body%20Checker.xml/ also I Rewrote the contents of the sample code the following.

Comment: var mailboxItem;
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
}

function validateBody(event) {

var dialog;
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('URL', {
height: 30,
width: 20,
displayInIframe: true
},
function (asyncResult) {
dialog = asyncResult.value;
dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage);
});
function processMessage(arg) {
dialog.close();
}
}

Comment: You should add a breakpoint to see the value of asyncResult. This will tell you whether the call to displayDialogAsync was successful or not. To add breakpoint you can add a line: "debugger;" inside function (asyncResult).

Comment: Outlook Add-ins Team -
Thank you for your advice.
A mysterious thing happened. This problem has disappeared since last week.
Maybe thanks to you guys fixing the dialog.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2356
Thanks for the work on this.